# Service Broker locks table even when committed

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I hope someone can explain some behavior I've got within the Service Broker, which is the first time I've used it so it's probably my lack of understanding.

I've got a complex set of stored procedures that have to run to publish a data model.  That's all working great, and is kicked off my sending a message to the broker to start the process.  However, I noticed when it was running that it'd lock a particular table, even though the update to it was very small.

So I set about seeing whether it was the broker, or just the part that's updating that table. I did this by stripping it all down to it's most basic form, and popping a `WAITFOR` in the stored procedure (UpdatePublishRunStatus) so I could delay completion of the procedure :

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE 
    [xxx].[PublishRuns] 
SET
    [Status] = @Status,
    [Message] = @Message,
    LastUpdated = getdate()
WHERE
    Id = @RunId

COMMIT TRANSACTION;


waitfor delay '00:02'
```

I then kick this off as follows:

```
declare @token uniqueidentifier 

declare @h uniqueidentifier
 , @xmlBody xml
    , @trancount int;
set nocount on;

set @xmlBody = CONVERT(XML,'<procedure><name>[xxx].[UpdatePublishRunStatus]</name><parameters><parameter Name="@RunId" BaseType="int" Precision="10" Scale="0" MaxLength="4">46</parameter><parameter Name="@Status" BaseType="int" Precision="10" Scale="0" MaxLength="4">20</parameter><parameter Name="@Message" BaseType="varchar" Precision="0" Scale="0" MaxLength="8">All good</parameter></parameters></procedure>')

begin dialog conversation @h
    from service [AsyncExecService]
    to service N'AsyncExecService', 'current database'
    with encryption = off;
select @token = [conversation_id]
    from sys.conversation_endpoints
    where [conversation_handle] = @h;


send on conversation @h (@xmlBody);

PRINT cast(@xmlBody as nvarchar(4000))
```

This will run fine.  However, while it's running - if I execute this from SSMS :

```
SELECT TOP (1000) *
  FROM [aaa].[xxx].[PublishRuns]
```

It locks up for the 2 minutes, until the service broker has completed the message.

Sticking `NOLOCK` hints obviously sorts out the read - but I don't understand why it's locking in the first place, particularly as I've committed the UPDATE before the `WAITFOR` kicks in.  The update takes milliseconds.

So my question is - why is it locking in this scenario? It's definitely the broker causing it, as running the same procedure in a query window, then running the select in another, does not exhibit the same behavior. This is what I'd expect, but there's obviously something I don't understand about the broker that's causing this.

Comment: I'm not an expert in Service Broker, but I have a theory.  After reading through the information about [Transactional Messaging](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171602(v=sql.105).aspx), I'm wondering if your `BEGIN TRANSACTION/COMMIT` is actually a _nested_ transaction within the actual invocation of the Service Broker message and your `COMMIT` is merely decrementing @@TRANCOUNT  In other words, I'm thinking the invocation of the Service Broker message is an implicit transaction and until the store procedure finishes, the implicit transaction (and locks held) cannot complete.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  I did wonder if that might be the case. Not quite sure how to prove it though - I can see the blocking in activity monitor but that's about it. I tried running a custom event session trace on locks but that didn't really reveal anything.  If this is the case I'm not sure how it'd be usable for what I'm doing - I don't want to end up locking the db tables in question while others tried to read, as I don't have full control over the other clients and their queries :(

Comment: I think you might be able to prove it via a few alternatives.  1). take out the `BEGIN TRANSACTION/COMMIT`, but leave your `WAITFOR`.  Is the table still locked for 2 minutes?  2). Modifying the stored procedure to check @@trancount>0 after your commit and capture that somehow (maybe email a message to yourself with the @@trancount.

Comment: @JamesCardno, the symptoms suggest nested transactions. SB doesn't do that automatically; statements are autocommitted like regular proc. Is `UpdatePublishRunStatus` the activated proc and, if so, can you add the complete code to your question (I don't see a `RECEIVE`). In the full implementation, do any of the nested procs have BEGIN TRAN?

Comment: In particular look at your activation process.  If using internal activation check the transaction handling in the internal activation procedure configured on the queue.  It should look like the example here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281526%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 which has a transaction.